# How to get rid of eclipse read only working sets [ Java Main Sources ] & [ Java Test Sources ] permanently?

Tags: eclipse, working-set

They are absolutely irritating since many a times when you sync open editor with project tree, eclipse jumps into these working sets which are completely missing project context.

Please note there is an ages old question about this but it refers to the "Other projects working set which I think is a very nice feature and I consider this question NOT a duplicate.

I am using  Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520
OS: Linux, v.5.19.0-42-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.33

[old question about readonly working set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515247/how-to-delete-a-read-only-working-set-in-eclipse)

Also I am aware of possibility of hiding those working sets but they show up all the time again and if I remove them it stays removed only for the specific session. Restarting eclipse brings them back.